# find row positions and column names of cells contanining inf in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I retrieve the column names and the rows of all the cells that contain inf in a multicolumns panda datarame `df`?

I have tried

```
inds = np.where(np.isinf(df)==True)
```

but I dont have the expected result

Answer (score 31, accepted):

row positions:

```
df.index[np.isinf(df).any(1)]
```

column names:

```
df.columns.to_series()[np.isinf(df).any()]
```

Demo:

```
In [163]: df
Out[163]:
minor             AAPL                        GS
             Adj Close        Volume   Adj Close     Volume
Date
2017-03-01  139.789993  3.627240e+07  252.710007  5218300.0
2017-03-02  138.960007           inf         inf  3020000.0
2017-03-03  139.779999  2.110810e+07  252.889999  3163700.0
2017-03-06  139.339996           inf         inf  2462300.0
2017-03-07  139.520004  1.726750e+07  250.899994  2414900.0
2017-03-08  139.000000           inf         inf  3574400.0
2017-03-09  138.679993  2.206520e+07  250.179993  3055700.0
2017-03-10  139.139999  1.948800e+07  248.380005  3357800.0
2017-03-13  139.199997  1.704240e+07  248.160004  1782700.0

In [164]: df.index[np.isinf(df).any(1)]
Out[164]: DatetimeIndex(['2017-03-02', '2017-03-06', '2017-03-08'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)

In [165]: df.columns.to_series()[np.isinf(df).any()]
Out[165]:
minor
AAPL   Volume        (AAPL, Volume)
GS     Adj Close    (GS, Adj Close)
dtype: object
```

Comment: Column names method causes typeerror: ufunc 'isinf' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: TypeError: ufunc 'isinf' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''. Getting this error from both the syntax

Comment: I'm getting the same error as Ujjwal with both examples.

Comment: @D.Reagan, i guess the error message is clear - it doesn't make much sense to look for infinity values in non-numeric columns like strings / timestamps / etc. So just pass a subset of __numeric__ columns

Comment: Here's how to select the numeric columns and filter the rows with inf
algo_runs.select_dtypes(include=np.number).loc[np.isinf(algo_runs.select_dtypes(include=np.number)).any(1)]

Comment: This may not work when you have categories in your df

Answer (score 4):

@MaxU's answer is helpful, but if you have a df with non-numeric columns it will error out; here's how to work around that:

```
numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
newdf = df.select_dtypes(include=numerics)
newdf.columns.to_series()[np.isinf(newdf).any()]
```